# Output data when clicking on a button in the same div in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I try to add a "add to favorite" on my website. Each time I click on the `likeButton`, I want to `console.log` the content of the div that contains the fav button. But in my example, when I hit the favButton, it triggered all div's content of the page. Why ?

```
<div class="ais-infinite-hits">
     <div class="ais-infinite-hits--item>
         <button class="toggle-icon-fav"></button>
         <div class="cote-actual-chf"> 20000 </div>
     </div>
     <div class="ais-infinite-hits--item>
         <button class="toggle-icon-fav"></button>
         <div class="cote-actual-chf"> 12345 </div>
     </div>
</div>


function pushDb() {
    let hitsItems = document.querySelectorAll('.ais-infinite-hits--item')
    if (hitsItems) {
        hitsItems.forEach(hitsItem => {
            let likeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle-icon-fav");
            if (likeButtons) {
                likeButtons.forEach(likeButton => {
                    likeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        let coteChfSave = hitsItem.querySelector('.cote_actual_chf').textContent;
                        const dataPush = {
                            coteChfSave: coteChfSave
                        }
                        console.log(dataPush)
                    })
                })
            }

        })
    }

}
pushDb()
```

The output:

```
{coteChfSave: 20000}, {coteChfSave:12345}...
```

The expected output:

```
{coteChefSave: 20000} when I Click the button in the same div...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you were running into was that you were running `document.querySelectorAll` for the likeButtons. This was getting every like button for every hitsItem and was adding a new event listener for each of the hitsItems. When you click on the buttons, then every single one of those event listeners would be called, and it would look like it's running the eventlisteners for all the buttons.

I used what you gave and just assumed that there's only 1 likeButton in each hitsItem to make the code a little neater.

If that's not the case, you should be able to use `hitsItem.querySelectorAll` instead of `document.querySelctorAll`. Or you can check if the current hitsItem contains the element in question. My second snippet shows it working with the querySelectorAll approach.

```js
function pushDb() {
  let hitsItems = document.querySelectorAll('.ais-infinite-hits--item')
  if (hitsItems) {
    hitsItems.forEach(hitsItem => {
      let likeButton = hitsItem.querySelector(".toggle-icon-fav");
      let coteChf = hitsItem.querySelector('.cote-actual-chf')
      if (coteChf && likeButton) {
        likeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
          let coteChfSave = coteChf.textContent;
          const dataPush = {
            coteChfSave: coteChfSave
          }
          console.log(dataPush)
        })
      }

    })
  }

}
pushDb()
```

```css
.ais-infinite-hits--item {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ais-infinite-hits">
  <div class="ais-infinite-hits--item">
    <button class="toggle-icon-fav">icon here</button>
    <div class="cote-actual-chf"> 20000 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ais-infinite-hits--item">
    <button class="toggle-icon-fav">icon here</button>
    <div class="cote-actual-chf"> 12345 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This snippet keeps the querySelectorAll behavior (in case that's needed)

```js
function pushDb() {
  let hitsItems = document.querySelectorAll('.ais-infinite-hits--item')
  if (hitsItems) {
    hitsItems.forEach(hitsItem => {
      let coteChf = hitsItem.querySelector('.cote-actual-chf')
      let likeButtons = hitsItem.querySelectorAll(".toggle-icon-fav");
      if (coteChf && likeButtons) {
        likeButtons.forEach((likeButton) => {
          likeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            let coteChfSave = coteChf.textContent;
            const dataPush = {
              coteChfSave: coteChfSave
            }
            console.log(dataPush)
          })
        })
      }

    })
  }

}
pushDb()
```

```css
.ais-infinite-hits--item {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ais-infinite-hits">
  <div class="ais-infinite-hits--item">
    <button class="toggle-icon-fav">icon here</button>
    <div class="cote-actual-chf"> 20000 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ais-infinite-hits--item">
    <button class="toggle-icon-fav">icon here</button>
    <div class="cote-actual-chf"> 12345 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working, I don't really understand why. Maybe because I use it in a render with Algolia's Instantsearch. Now only the first `hitsItem` is triggered

Comment: Can you put up a live example of what you are working with? Otherwise it'll be hard to figure out what's going wrong.